# CSS layout, header, footer, 2 cols, fixed 100% height - no vertical window scrolling on computer (designer GUI layout)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

EDIT: Thought I had found my own pure flex-based solution but this had issues enabling content scroll on the nav / left hand section of the middle row. I posted my current grid solution which overcomes this. I have edited the question to include the scroll requirement.

---

I am trying to make a 'designer GUI' layout. It has to be usable on computer and tablet only - small devices would just be unusable.

The layout is intended to be used as a web page design tool:

- Computer: [Run the snippet to see it for real] There is a full width header that will hold info about the item being worked on, and there is a footer with more status info at the bottom of the viewport. The middle row holds a navigator column at roughly 30% viewport width, and the right is a preview column consuming the remaining viewport width.  No page-scrolling must occur even when the nav list is long, but the content of the nav-list **MUST** be able to scroll vertically. Imaging a lot of links, for example.
- Tablet: Ideally in landscape mode the layout would be as for the computer view. In portrait mode the columns in the middle row should stack, retaining the same height as pre-stack, and clearly page scrolling now has to be allowed.

The snippet below is my attempt at the computer version.

**Issues**

- At the moment the widths of col1 is a percentage and the position of col2 is the same percentage value, giving a niggly overlap.
- How to stack when we go to the smaller viewport? I understand breakpoints and media queries - what I can't get is how to take that rigid fixed 100% height and bust it when required.
- Overall I feel that I should be using flexbox but that's voodoo to me!

Can anyone help? I am assuming this must have been done already but my web searches are mostly uncovering old pre-flex hacks or the solutions I have found do not give the stack feature.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#row1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
}

#row2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 80vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#row3 {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;       
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 20%;  /* This is an issue as it is a problem for correct positioning */
}

#content1 {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 100%;
}

#contentInner {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">Header</div>
  <div id="row2">
    <div id="col1">
      <div id='content1'>
        <div id="contentInner">

          Amet nostrud amet adipisicing eu enim voluptate ipsum consequat occaecat consequat mollit tempor ut nisi. Amet aute eu ex pariatur esse in. Cillum aute aute in cillum incididunt aute dolor excepteur Lorem. Velit in incididunt nostrud magna consectetur
          deserunt exercitation ea. Cupidatat aliquip qui duis irure laborum ex laborum qui nulla qui adipisicing occaecat elit. Mollit qui mollit occaecat ex aliquip est. Excepteur consequat magna elit veniam dolor dolor mollit incididunt culpa cillum
          velit aliqua. Quis Lorem fugiat consectetur nostrud eiusmod. Eiusmod culpa excepteur nisi id qui laboris proident eu enim officia laboris deserunt laboris non. Pariatur nisi est fugiat sunt.

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="col2">col2</div>
    <div id="col3">col3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row3">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it using [Flexible Box Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) or you can do it with [Grid](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid). There are advantages and disadvantages with using either. Flexbox will most likely need a container with three children -- header first, footer last, and where the middle child will in turn have two children -- the navigation and the child element containing the bulk of your content. With Grid, you can get away using a single container with four children for the entire layout. So it depends.

Comment: @amn Thank you for your suggestion of grid. I found the flex approach to be problematic in Chrome in regard to triggering scrolling on the nav section, but the grid version had no such issues.

Comment: You mean instead of overflowing, your nav section height is constrained to the maximum height of the "page main" element parent? I am pretty sure Flexbox allows whatever it is you found Grid to allow you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own answer using grid instead of flex box.

I was prompted to do this because of an emerging issue with the flexbox approach. In the left hand / nav section I needed the content to scroll. Try as I might I could never achieve that - though this 'may' have been due to using Fomantic-UI for the contents as FUI has some pretty stern and opinionated CSS going on.

See the example here for convenience: https://jsfiddle.net/VanquishedWombat/9L57j8so/19/

Overall the grid approach made more sense to me and seemed to have less black-magic involved. The solution uses two grids - the outer gives the header, middle and footer, then the middle contains a second grid that gives the two sections. The media query re-vamps the inner grid and cell positions.

```js
// Note the JS is just for fun and not important to the grid CSS layout!

var cnt = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {


  $('body').on('click', '#cull', function() {

    $('.wrapper li').each(function() {
      cnt = cnt + 1;
      if (cnt > 5) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    })
  })

  $('body').on('click', '#add', function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1) {
      $('ul').append($("<li>Menu Entry</li>"))
    }

  })

});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Changes in media query to double this */
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.page-main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* can grow as big as needed */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* The magic dust that is needed to make it scroll - see http://geon.github.io/programming/2016/02/24/flexbox-full-page-web-app-layout */
}

.page-header {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: MediumSpringGreen;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
}

.page-content {
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: ForestGreen;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

#content {
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#contentInner {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: lime;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}


/* When we hit the small width breakpoint, double the height of the wrapper to 2 x vp height, 
make the page content flex wrap, and make the page content columns 100% width to force the wrap. Also
noe make the  page content columns 40% height to retain their original height now the patent is double height. 
*/

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 200vh;
    max-height: 200vh;
  }
  .page-content {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  #col1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;
  }
  #col2 {
    background-color: ForestGreen;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="page-header">
    This is the top line fixed at 50px height.
  </header>
  <main class="page-main">
    <div class='page-content'>
      <div id='col1' class='col'>


        <div id='content'>
          <div id="contentInner">
            <button id='cull'>
          Click to cull some menu entries - border should not shrink</button>
            <ul>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
            </ul>
            <button id='add'>
          Click to add 10 more menu entries - should enable scroll</button>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='col2' class='col'>
        Preview content
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    This is the footer fixed at 20px height
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at flex box and min-width to set a breakpoint.

example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow:auto;
}
aside {
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}
aside,
section {
  max-height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
section {
  min-width: 300px;
  flex: 3;
}
header,
footer {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
main {
  background: salmon;
}
section {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header> header any height 
  <p> run me in full page to test behavior on resize</header>
  <main>
    <aside> aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>aside content <br>End  </aside>
    <section> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> wider content <br> End </section>
  </main>
  <footer> footer any height</footer>
</div>
```

tutorial/reminder : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Its not clear in your answer how the break point code would rewire the css ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat add the min-width et, it will fire the break point. here for the example it is : 200px + 300px = 500px . Tune this to your needs ;).

Comment: The question asks for the red & green sections to stack when the small-screen media query fires. Your solution reduced their widths which is an interesting feature but not what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat they stack under 500px, you have to set you own width here , an answser is at first an hint , not a job done ;)

Comment: Apologies - my Chrome was running the snippet media queries very slowly and I did not persevere to 500px so missed the stack. Note the addition in my question of the need to have the nav section be scrollable.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat sorry, i think i misunderstand you here , both element inside main do scroll when you run the snippet. Where does it go wrong for you ? or is it your browser/os not behaving as expected ?

Comment: I'm trying to get to the bottom of it atm. I'm using Fomantic-UI components within the nav section and that might be the cause. FUI has some quite stern CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own flexbox-based answer developed after some more research.

I posted the snippet below but it is easier to resize the screen in the version in  [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VanquishedWombat/4nfe7yja/60/).

I got stuck on the scrolling nav content in the left hand middle column which seemed to disobey the usual rules of setting max-height = 100% with overflow-y = auto/scroll. The final breakthrough was [this article](http://geon.github.io/programming/2016/02/24/flexbox-full-page-web-app-layout) which solved for me the issue of the nav column overflowing the page and pushing the footer out of view. [Trick is to have overflow=hidden on the flex parent!].

I rewrote the layout using two flex solutions. The wrapper-flex gives the three rows, and the page-main flex gives the columns in the middle row.

To get the small-screen stack approach, a media query is used to:

- double the wrapper height from 100vh (100% of vertical height of viewport) to 200vh,
- switch on the stack function in the page-main row
- make the columns in that row both 100% width to trigger the wrap
- make the columns in that row 50% height so they effectively stay the same as before.

Important: run the snippet full page then F12 and resize the page to see the breakpoint run at 750px width.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;     /* Changes in media query to double this */
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.page-main {
  flex-grow: 1;   /* can grow as big as needed */
  overflow: hidden;  /* The magic dust that is needed to make it scroll - see http://geon.github.io/programming/2016/02/24/flexbox-full-page-web-app-layout */
}

.page-header {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: MediumSpringGreen;
}

.page-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


#col1 {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  width: 30%;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: ForestGreen;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

#contentInner {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* When we hit the small width breakpoint, double the height of the wrapper to 2 x vp height, 
make the page content flex wrap, and make the page content columns 100% width to force the wrap. Also
noe make the  page content columns 40% height to retain their original height now the patent is double height. 
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 200vh;
    max-height: 200vh;
  }
  .page-content {
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
  }
  #col1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
 #col2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="page-header">
    This is the top line
  </header>
  <main class="page-main">
    <div class='page-content'>
      <div id='col1' class='col'>


        <div id='content'>
          <div id="contentInner">
            <ul>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>              
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
              <li>Menu Entry</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='col2' class='col'>
        Preview content
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    This is the footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Important: run the snippet full page then F12 and resize the page to see the breakpoint run at 750px width.

Comment: This should be part of your question, not an answer, arguably.

Comment: @amn Have thought about your comment re this being part of the question. When I wrote the question I did not have this solution. This is, IMHO, a solution and the one that I am using and is so far viable. Answering your own questions is a valid action in SO. I feel that there could be others with better / cleaner alternatives so I am leaving the question in place. There could also be other folk in the future who could benefit from my own attempt at the answer, and the other one I posted that uses grid.